# How run next.js with node-sharp for docker

Tags: docker, next.js, sharp

I have a problem implementing sharp for Dockerfile.

```
Error: 'sharp' is required to be installed in standalone mode for the image 
optimization to function correctly
```

Next.js with sharp works fine for local developing:

- next 12.0.1
- sharp 0.30.2
- node 16.xx
- npm 8.xx
- OS - macOS Monterey - 12.2.1, M1 PRO

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
```

}

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next-i18next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next-sitemap.js ./cd
COPY --from=builder /app/jsconfig.json ./jsconfig.json
COPY --from=builder /app/data/ ./data
COPY --from=builder /app/components/ ./components
COPY --from=builder /app/utils/ ./utils
COPY --from=builder /app/assets/ ./assets

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size 
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**.env file:**

```
NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp next start
```

Sharp is installed in package.json

I checked both Next/Vercel tuts:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sharp
- https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production

**RUN Docker:**

```
docker build --no-cache . -t website-app && docker run --name website -p 3000:3000 website-app
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/node_modules/sharp` instead of `/tmp/node_modules/sharp`?

Comment: @SilvinoEscalona I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Facing the same error. Have you figured it out??

Comment: @Anandhu not yet, I have tried everything but without success.

Comment: @miko866 this worked for me.

FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH /app/node_modules/sharp next start

Comment: Facing the same issue with no end in sight, would you mind sharing your Dockerfile @Anandhu ?

Comment: Actually I was wrong lol. Still didn't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 5):

For the final step (the one labeled "runner") in your `Dockerfile`, replace the base image with [`node:16-slim`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/16-slim/images/sha256-904fa395a577db4dfe368e499c7752e948330d9531008db90fceb8a34c1ee013?context=explore). This image is Debian-based, so it is approximately 20 MB larger than the `alpine` variant, but it has the binaries required to run `sharp`.

When using a similar `Dockerfile` to yours, I found that the `NEXT_SHARP_PATH` environment variable was not needed when using a Debian-based Node image.

And for reference, here is the NextJS documentation about the error message: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production

**Update**: You may also be able to specify the `libc` implementation found in your base Docker image by using the following flags:

```bash
RUN npm_config_platform=linux npm_config_arch=x64 npm_config_libc=glibc npm ci
```

For more information about what these flags are, see the [documentation for sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform).

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i sharp
```

this fix the problem for me

Comment: Unfortunately this also makes the image 600mb bigger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install `sharp` on **alpine** image, you need to rebuild it after the first install.

```
npm install --save sharp
npm rebuild --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=musl sharp
```

which can be written as `Dockerfile` as follows

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install && \
    npm rebuild --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=musl sharp

RUN npm run build

...
```

P.S. If you do the above, you won't need to set `NEXT_SHARP_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I removed `NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp next start` from .env
Local docker doesn't work with node-sharp without `NEXT_SHARP_PATH` and that is weird.

But I deployed it in my K8s Cluster with Docker and it works as is expected.

Comment: what does this mean? remove from `NEXT_SHARP_PATH` from .env file but have it be present and defined in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, is to change the version of Alpine Linux in the Dockerfile:
`FROM node:18-alpine AS deps` (instead of node:16)

Adding or removing node-sharp in my .env file didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with added several command in dockerfile :

1. add "RUN npm i sharp" in deps section
2. add "COPY --from=deps /root/.npm /root/.npm" in builder section before RUN npm run build
3. add "ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/app/node_modules/sharp" in runner section

also if you use same image for deps, builder, and runner. I just add "RUN npm i sharp" in runner section to solved this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `pnpm`, you need only 2 steps:

1. put this in your `package.json`:

```json
    "pnpm": {
        "supportedArchitectures": {
            "os": [
                "current"
            ],
            "cpu": [
                "x64",
                "arm64"
            ]
        }
    }
```

2. install `sharp` normally

```
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline
RUN pnpm install sharp@0.32.6
```

don't forget to remove `sharp` from your `package.json`. you also don't need `ENV_SHARP_PATH` either.

if this is not working, then do `rm -rf node_modules && pnpm install` & it will work.

[My full dockerfile example is here.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35296#discussioncomment-8626231)

[This discussion on Next.js Github has different solutions.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35296)

Next.js doc has [a simple guide on it here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production).

[Sharp also recommends this here.](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install)